# How to kill a tmux pane along with the process running on it?

Tags: tmux

Let's say you run a command like `grunt serve` on a tmux pane,
and you kill the pane on which the command is running. I found that
the process is not killed:

```
ps aux | grep grunt
```

still shows that grunt is running even though the pane is gone.
How do you kill a tmux pane along with the process(es)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the [tmux-safekill](https://github.com/jlipps/tmux-safekill) plugin useful.

I wanted it to kill Ruby processes, so I had to fork the repo to add that functionality in, so I'm sure you could do the same for grunt processes if you don't get all the functionality you need from the repo directly.

Answer (score 21):

To stop the program running you can close the pane by entering `<C-B> x` and then entering `y`.

Comment: It's important to note that this also closes the pane, which may not be intended

Answer (score 6):

Use <kbd>Ctrl + b</kbd>¹, <kbd>></kbd> to get a menu with this and other useful commands:

[image: screenshot]

This is what uses [the Spotify plugin](https://github.com/xamut/tmux-spotify).

¹ Or the chosen tmux escape sequence.

##### Other notes and sources

```bash
tmux list-keys | grep display-menu  # 

curl cht.sh/tmux                    # Online cheatsheet
```

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/tmux

Answer (score 4):

Just do:    `<CTRL-B>:kill-pane`